# How can I use the capability of a VPN extension of Firefox or Chrome for my activities out of these browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I am currently using a very good VPN in Chrome (also in Firefox).

Is there any way that when I turn on the VPN, I can also use its ability in other browsers or for every internet connections on the Windows? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Only possible if the VPN in question has a downloadable client on OS level or can be setup on OS level.

The browser simply does not have enough privileges to affect the system outside of the browser, and if the browser can't, then neither can its plugins.

Comment: It does not have a client to be installed on the OS. How can I give this privilege to the browser to operate on OS level? @LPChip

Comment: If it doesn't have a client for the OS, then this VPN can't do it, and you need to switch to a different VPN provider.